# Pandas: Taking slices from a DataFrame and recombining them into a separate DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I'm trying to take slices from a DataFrame and recombine them into a separate DF. However I'm getting a Value error 'cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'

```
run1 = df['run_1']
run2 = df['run_2']

a = run1[305:340]
b = run1[258:270]
c = run2[258:270]
d = run2[305:340]

first_slice = a.combine_first(b)
second_slice = c.combine_first(d)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(first_slice, second_slice)
```

Comment: Can you post data to reproduce your error, also what are you trying to achieve here? Are you creating a new df from the slices? In which case your params to the DataFrame ctor are not going to work, you may want `pd.concat([first_slice, second_slice])`

Comment: oops I wasn't putting the brackets in concat... thanks :)

Comment: So does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your code will fail as the parmas to the `DataFrame` ctor are:

> pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None,
>   copy=False)

So even if it didn't complain it wouldn't produce what you want. There are various methods of [joining, merging and concatenating](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) multiple dfs, in your case `concat` is what you want:

`df1 = pd.concat([first_slice, second_slice])`